# How to correctly extend and implement Java generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

UPDATE:

Thanks to @RC for solving this for me:

```
public class DataHandler<I, T extends IDataStore<I>> implements IHollywood<T, I>
```

From his comment I learned how to fix the ActorImpl:

```
public class ActorImpl extends DataHandler <Long, Actor> implements IHollywood
```

Solved.

I am currently trying to learn Java and am having some difficulty with generics. I am stuck on how to correctly implement a generic interface using two different type parameters and then extend this new implementation by two other interfaces that extend the original interface.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public interface IDataStore<ID> extends Serializable

public interface IHollywood<T extends IDataStore <ID>, ID>
{
    List<T> retrieve() throws Exception;
    void sotre(T t) throws Exception;
}

public interface IActor extends IHollywood <Actor, Long>
public interface IDirector extends IHollywood <Director, Long>

public class DataHandler<T> implements IHollywood <IDataStore<T>, T>

public class ActorImpl implements IActor extends DataHandler
public class DirectorImpl implements IDirector extends DataHandler
```

I have two points of confusion:

1. What is the correct signature for DataHandler? Currently I am using `public class DataHandler<T> implements IHollywood <IDataStore<T>, T>` and I know I am passing `T` as two parameters wrongly but can’t figure out the right way
2. What is the correct way for `ActorImpl` and `DirectorImpl` to implement `IHollywood` and extend `DataHandler` declaration?

Edit/Update:

I'll try to give more details:

```
// 1- support serialization
// provide interface to create/store/query persisted data
    public interface IDataStore<ID> extends Serializable   
    public interface IHollywood<T extends IDataStore <ID>, ID>

// 2- provide an interface for Actor specific methods
    public class Actor{}...
    public interface IActor extends IHollywood <Actor, Long>

// Implement IActor
    public class ActorImpl implements IActor

// 3- provide an interface for Director specific methods
    public class Director{}...
    public interface IDirector extends IHollywood <Director, Long>

// 4- Implement Director
    public class DirectorImpl implements IDirector

// 5- Instead of CRUD, I’ll use a better name
// Implement retrieve()/store()/find methods
    public class DataHandler <T> implements IHollywood <IDataStore<T>, T>
```

1. This way, I can use DataHandler to implement retrieve()/store()/find() methods of `IHollywood`
2. I can derive `ActorImpl` and `DirectorImpl` from `DataHandler` to use its retrieve()/store()/find() methods
3. I know `IActor` and `IDirector` extend `IHollywood` but I do not want to duplicate implementation of retrieve()/store()/find() methods of `IHollywood`. I want the `DataHandler` to implement them and `ActorImpl` and `DirectorImpl` to just inherit and use them, besides providing their own specific methods in their own implementation.

I hope this clarifies a bit what I need help with.

Comment: 1) Interfaces *extends* interfaces. Classes *extends* classes and *implements* interfaces. So `ActorImpl` cannot `extends` the interface `IHollywood`. --- 2) What is `Actor` in the `IActor` declaration?

Comment: `ActorImpl` doesn't need to implement `IHollywood` since `IActor` extends it (and `ActorImpl` uses raw form of `IHollyWood`). `CRUD` also extends `IHollywood`, which confuses me, since `Actor` and `Director` do seem like hollywood entities (they exist *in* hollywood, they themselves are not an instance of hollywood. might wanna change your names/relationships) crud is an ancronym representing persistant storage behavior. So what is `IHollywood` supposed to be?

Comment: What you ask is unclear, but your probably want `public class DataHander<T, I> implements IHollywood <T extends IDataStore<I>, I>`

Comment: @RC I get: Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Comment: my bad it's `public class DataHander<I, T extends IDataStore<I>> implements IHollywood<T, I>`

Comment: @RC Thank you so much for your help. I understand generics mechanics a lot better now.

Comment: No problem, may I suggest you add a self-answer to your question an accept it? (you will get some rep for that and it *might* help some future reader)

Comment: @RC How do I accept my own answer. I see no option to accept.

Comment: You have to wait a little time, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @RC Thank you. I appreciate your help, and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @RC for solving this for me:

```
public class DataHander<I, T extends IDataStore<I>> implements IHollywood<T, I>
```

From his comment I learned how to fix the ActorImpl:

```
public class ActorImpl extends DataHander <Long, Actor> implements IHollywood
```

Solved.